# Cannot find class on project

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to search for  class="reports-submenu" in my entire solution, but it will not show up on any files.  I thought it would show up in CSS file, but it did not find it.  I do a quick find with "reports-submenu" and nothing shows up

```
<li style="visibility: hidden; display: none" id="ReportLi"><a id="MainReport"  
style="visibility: visible">
                    Reports</a> <span class="reports-submenu">
                        @Html.ActionLink("My Reports", "Index", new { controller = 
"Report" }, new { id = "Reports1", @style = "visibility:hidden;display:none" })
                        @Html.ActionLink("Standard Reports", "ReportStandard", new { 
controller = "Report" }, new { id = "Report2", @style = "visibility:hidden;display:none" 
})                           
                    </span></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've found it in your view.

Just because it is used in the view doesn't mean that it is defined in a css file at all. Maybe someone removed it from CSS file and forgot to remove it from the view?